# Accessing Values In Nested Dict In Python - String Indices Must Be Integers

Tags: python, api, flask

I've gone through other similar problems here, but still can't identify my problem.

I have this JSON data returned from an API call:

```
{
  "Open": {
    "1638316800000": 120.5400009155,
    "1640995200000": 106.1399993896,
    "1643673600000": 67.2799987793,
    "1646092800000": 65.4300003052,
    "1648771200000": 50.1800003052,
    "1651104000000": 31.5699996948
  },
  "High": {
    "1638316800000": 126.75,
    "1640995200000": 106.8000030518,
    "1643673600000": 71.5,
    "1646092800000": 66.5400009155,
    "1648771200000": 50.2599983215,
    "1651104000000": 31.6900005341
  },
  "Low": {
    "1638316800000": 88.4000015259,
    "1640995200000": 50.0,
    "1643673600000": 53.5,
    "1646092800000": 33.4599990845,
    "1648771200000": 30.5799999237,
    "1651104000000": 30.5209999084
  },
  "Close": {
    "1638316800000": 103.6900024414,
    "1640995200000": 65.7399978638,
    "1643673600000": 67.5599975586,
    "1646092800000": 50.2400016785,
    "1648771200000": 31.2199993134,
    "1651104000000": 30.6100006104
  }
}
```

All I'm trying to do is assign the "Close" data to a new variable close and return close instead of the entire dictionary response.

Here is what I'm currently trying and I've tried different variations and all keep returning "string indices must be integers"

```
@app.route("/history")
def display_history():

    symbol = request.args.get('symbol', default="AAPL")
    period = request.args.get('period', default="1y")
    interval = request.args.get('interval', default="1mo")
    quote = yf.Ticker(symbol)
    hist = quote.history(period=period, interval=interval)
    data = hist.to_json()
    close = data["Close"]
    return close
```

Comment: The Python interpreter has identified the problem for you: You are trying to use something else than an integer as index for a string. Given the code you have shown, it seems to be `data["Close"]` meaning that `data` is a string and apparently you expected it to be something different.

Comment: Are you looking for `close = hist["Close"]`? And if you are lucky, `return close.to_json()` exists.

Comment: Be careful, @tevemadar 's solution `close = hist['Close']` returns a `pandas.Series` and not a Python dictionary. It could be very helpful, but you can also use `close = hist['Close'].to_dict()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `data`, which is a string with json format, as your interpreter told you.

In order to read it as a dictionary with the key "Close", you can use the function [`loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=loads#json.loads) from `json` package. It deserializes the string to a Python dictionary :

```
data = hist.to_json()
data = json.loads(data)
close = data["Close"]
```

Additionally, it appears that `Ticker.history()`, from `yfinance` module, returns a pandas Dataframe. If it is the case, you can use this instead :

```
data = hist.to_dict()
close = data['Close']
```

This way, the data is not converted to Json then back to Python dictionary again but straight to a dictionary.

Comment: Or just... don't convert it to JSON and back again?

Comment: Of course, I honestly have no idead what `hist` looks like ...

Comment: @mkrieger1 I edited the answer since apparently `yf.Ticker.history()` returns a `pd.DataFrame`.